# R: how to account maximum duplicates in each elements of a vector

Tags: r, vector, duplicates, max

How can I account maximum duplicates in each elements of a vector
Example: `x <- c("a001", "a002,a003,a003", "a004,a004,a004", "a004,a006,a007")`
expected result is: `c(1, 2, 3, 1)`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try:

```
vapply(strsplit(x,","), function(y) max(tapply(y,y,length)),1L)
#[1] 1 2 3 1
```

Comment: Would you help with another questions:

Comment: How can I account the number of different elements in a vector Example: x <- c("a001", "a002,a003,a003", "a004,a004,a004", "a004,a006,a007") expected result is: c(1, 2, 1, 3)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is

```
library(qdapTools)
do.call(pmax,mtabulate(strsplit(x, ',')))
#[1] 1 2 3 1
```

If we need the length of unique number of elements,

```
library(dplyr)
strsplit(x, ',') %>% 
         sapply(., n_distinct) 
#[1] 1 2 1 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sapply(strsplit(x, ","), function(x) max(table(x)))
```

and, for @mi3567's comment on @nicola's answer

```
lengths(lapply(strsplit(x, ","), unique))
```

Comment: Clarified; OP asked a follow-up in a comment to another answer

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- c("a001", "a002,a003,a003", "a004,a004,a004", "a004,a006,a007")
y <- sapply(x, function(z){
  x1 <- unlist(strsplit(z, ","))
  return(rev(table(x1))[1])
})
unname(y)
# [1] 1 2 3 1
```

For your second question.

```
y1 <- sapply(x, function(z){
  x1 <- unlist(strsplit(z, ","))
  return(length(unique(x1)))
})
unname(y1)
# [1] 1 2 1 3
```